# validate one bean of another controller (Spring MVC portlet)

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, portlet

I trying to do something kind of weird, but I need to do it though...

I've two beans in two controllers and 2 validators: let's say...

```
BeanA {
    private String propertyA;
}

BeanB {
    private String propertyB;
}
```

To save the bean A, I need to validate the bean B as well, so I'm trying to do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(params = ACTION_SAVE_BEAN_A)
public final void doActionSave (@ModelAttribute(value = ServletContextKeys.BEAN_A) BeanA beanA,
        Errors errors, ActionRequest actionrequest, ActionResponse actionResponse, PortletSession portletSession) {

    BeanB beanB = getBeanB();
    validatorBeanB.validate(beanB, errors);
    if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
        //Save beanA
        beanA.save();
    }

}
```

And my validator code:

```
validatorBeanB{

private void validatePropertyB(Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, PROPERTY_B, BEANB_ERRORS + PROPERTY_B);
      }

   }
```

But executing this code, I receive an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'propertyB' of bean class [BeanA]: Bean property 'propertyB' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

I understand the error, but I need to find a workaround to fix it, and I can't just put the propertyB in the beanA (actually, it isn't just a property, there are quite more in the bean...)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of declare the Errors in the method (it came with the Bean A asociated by the target field) I create a new one before the validation call. Something like:

```
BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(beanB,"BeanB");

BeanBValidator.validate(beanB, errors);
```